# Is it possible to maintain values across cells in excel?

Tags: excel

Here's what I'm working with:

```
    A     B     C     D      E     F
1 |  2/22    |    2/28   |    3/1     |
2 |Est | Act | Est | Act |  Est | Act | 
3 | 8    10     2     1      1     0  |
```

In this example, the date cells are merged, the goal being that the date should span across its Estimated and Actual columns beneath.

What I'm trying to do is to get the sum of these values where:

If today is less than or equal to the dates in column A here, sum the Actual values since that date is past. Otherwise, if today is greater than the dates in column A, sum the Estimated values, since I'm trying to get a total of hours including the forecasted ones.

So I wrote a formula which I thought would do this:

```
=SUM(IF(TODAY()<=A1:F1,IF(A2:F2="Act",A3:F3),IF(TODAY()>A1:F1,IF(A2:F2="Est",A3:F3))))
```

The day I started this was 2/28, and my hope would be the total would be 11 (Act) + 1 Est = 12.

In this case, though, since my formula looks at all of the cells underneath the "merged" ones, I'm not sure its possible. If I print out the value of A1 and B1 in this example, I'd get Feb-14 and Jan-00 respectively which is a problem for my formula

Does this make sense? Is it possible to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something a bit like that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:F1<=TODAY())*(A1:F1<>"")*B3:G3)+SUMPRODUCT((A1:F1>TODAY())*A3:F3)
```

The multiplications are what apply the conditions.

`A1:F1<=TODAY()` gets all the dates that are today and before.

`A1:F1<>""` ensures that the blank cells are not included (in merged cells, only the top rightmost cell address has the value and the others are considered blank).

`B3:G3` is a range that starts with actual values.

`SUMPRODUCT((A1:F1<=TODAY())*(A1:F1<>"")*B3:G3)` gets the sum of all the actual values.

A little less complicated `SUMPRODUCT((A1:F1>TODAY())*A3:F3)` gets the sum of all estimated values.

---

In more detail, `A1:F1<=TODAY()` returns an array of true and false, as does `A1:F1<>""` and `A1:F1>TODAY()`. In your example, we have `A1:F1<=TODAY()` which is:

```
{2/22,0,2/28,0,3/1,0}<=TODAY()
```

which gives the array `{TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}`. Similarly, `` `A1:F1<>"" `` gives the array:

```
{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}
```

When multiplied together, they get converted into 1s and 0s, 1 being true and 0 being false. `(A1:F1<=TODAY())*(A1:F1<>"")` thus gives the array:

```
{1,0,1,0,0,0}
```

because you get 1 only when `TRUE` gets multiplied by another `TRUE` and you get 0 as soon as there is a `FALSE` involved in the multiplication.

The array then becomes:

```
{1,0,1,0,0,0}*B3:G3
```

Which is:

```
{1,0,1,0,0,0}*{10,2,1,1,0,0}
```

And giving:

```
(10,0,1,0,0,0}
```

`SUMPRODUCT` then adds those numbers to give 11`

Likewise, if we have `SUMPRODUCT((A1:F1>TODAY())*A3:F3)`, we get:

```
SUMPRODUCT({FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}*{8,10,2,1,1,0})
```

Which gives 1.

Comment: This is absolutely excellent - thank you for it and the great explanation.  Very much appreciated!